# Which references am I missing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, openxml-sdk

[image: Missing one reference]

I am missing one reference for `.Cells` and the picture shows all the references that I have tried. Which one am i still missing?
[image]

Comment: Please post your code as formatted code, not a screenshot.  That's very difficult to read and impossible to copy & paste into a text editor.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev How would that help? He's using `OfficeOpenXml`, the [ExcelWorksheet](https://excelpackage.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ExcelPackageWinRt/ExcelPackageWinRt/ExcelWorksheet.cs) class doesn't contain a `Cells` property, that's his problem.

Comment: Do you want the `Cell` method and not a `Cells` property? (which as dtsg points out doesn't appear to exist) - e.g. worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value = row * col;

Comment: @petelids actually it exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486391/cant-write-data-to-existing-xlsx-file

Comment: @taimeili123 - I think they are using [EpPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) which *does* have a `Cells` property in the [`ExcelWorksheet`](https://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet.cs) class. You appear to be using [ExcelPackage](https://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) which doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the [`ExcelPackage`](https://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) project and the [`EPPlus`](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) project. I can see how as they share namespaces and class names (I don't know the history of either to know if they're related or not).

You have a reference to the `ExcelPackage` dll in your example. The [`ExcelWorksheet`](https://excelpackage.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ExcelPackageWinRt/ExcelPackageWinRt/ExcelWorksheet.cs) class there doesn't have a `Cells` property; instead it has a `Cell` method.

The [`ExcelWorksheet`](https://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet.cs) class in `EPPlus` *does* have a `Cells` property that returns an `ExcelRange`. The `ExcelRange` in turn has an indexer that looks like this which would allow the code you have to work:

```
public ExcelRange this[int Row, int Col]
```

To get your code to work using `ExcelPackage` you will need to change to using the method:

```
worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value = (row * col).ToString();
```

Note that the `Value` property is a `string` so I'm calling `ToString()`

If you would prefer to keep your code as is you could remove the reference to `ExcelPackage` and add a reference to `EPPlus` instead (which is available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)). I have no idea which is better but running your code against both (with the above fix for the `ExcelPackage` version) gives me a warning when loading the file created by `ExcelPackage` in Excel but it doesn't for the one created via `EPPlus`.